# Equate timestamp with day name in a query and get result set w.r.t day name in PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I want to equate timestamp with day name in PostgreSQL and I want result set with respect to day name. I tried to use sub query and some functions too but getting syntax errors and function not exist SQL errors. Please help.

I tried to use to_char and to_timestamp functions but I am getting stuck to syntax errors when I am binding them into sub query.First I wrote this query which extracts day from timestamp.

```
select to_char(TO_TIMESTAMP(1534994169000 / 1000), 'Day');
```

Then I tried to use this query in sub query shown in code.

```
select * from tests where testtimestamp = (to_timestamp(TO_TIMESTAMP(1531803015000 / 1000), 'Day'));

select * from tests where testtimestamp = (select to_timestamp(to_char(TO_TIMESTAMP(1534994169000 / 1000), 'Day')))
```

Errors that I am getting is

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function to_timestamp(timestamp with time
>   zone, unknown) does not exist   Hint: No function matches the given
>   name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
>   Position: 44   ERROR: function to_timestamp(timestamp with time zone,
>   unknown) does not exist   Hint: No function matches the given name and
>   argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.   Position:
>   44   ERROR: function to_timestamp(timestamp with time zone, unknown)
>   does not exist   Hint: No function matches the given name and argument
>   types. You might need to add explicit type casts.   Position: 44

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve. Can you please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it, do not post that in a comment) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your formatting produces a text output (ie. Wednesday) you need to also do a conversion on the timestamp field in your table to make an equality comparison. I suppose something like this.

```
select 
       * 
  from 
       tests 
 where 
       to_char(TO_TIMESTAMP(testtimestamp / 1000), 'Day') 
       = 
       to_char(TO_TIMESTAMP(1534994169000 / 1000), 'Day');
```

Make sure you use to_char and to_timestamp (in your first query above you did to_timestamp twice, which is what caused the error). If you do happen to work this out, you may want to look into functional indexes to speed this up.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `EXTRACT`

```
WHERE extract( day from testtimestamp)
   = extract ( day from TO_TIMESTAMP(1534994169000 / 1000) )
```